# How to use variables from another function in a another function?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make a function that writes the scores of a user's quiz to a file along with their username. However the variable that the username is stored in was created inside a different function - how do I use a variable from one function in another function?

Comment: Please provide some code that you have written as a minimum verifiable example.

Comment: Rather than describing your code, can you please give a representative example? Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: @G.Nachtigal I guess that's a correct duplicate target but then again it also uses `global` which I think should be avoided if possible; the OP would _presumably_ be better `return`ing a value from the first function. Then again, we have no solid basis to make the call because there's no code.

Comment: If it is a local variable (which it probably *should* be) then you should be returning the value

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you pass parameters to functions and return values

```
username = get_username()
write_results(username)
```